# Android Support Library Gradle Conflict

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I am having an issue regarding the inconsistent version of Android support libraries used in my app, but after specifying the exact same version in my Gradle I still get the same error.

The problem is specifically between `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'` and `'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'`. Even after specifying to `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'` it still says there is a conflict with `support-v4:24.0.0`. Any help to resolve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Edit: Below is my entire build.gradle file.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties");
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 48
        versionName "5.1.5"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'


    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'

    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.4.0'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.13.0/Parse-1.13.0.jar')

    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'

    // SugarORM
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    // Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'

    // Google play services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.0'

    // Timber logging
    compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.0'

    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.7'

    // Crashlytics
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.7@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: please post your build.gradle file of app module

Comment: @AbhishekAryan done

Comment: One or more of your transitive dependencies is requesting `24.0.0` of some portion of the Android Support Library that you are not requesting directly yourself, resulting in this conflict. You will need to run a Gradle dependency report and find out what is causing the problem, then manually request those artifacts yourself with your desired version (presently, `23.1.0`). Note that you may break those dependencies, as they are expecting something newer (`24.0.0` is newer than `23.1.0`).

Comment: Ah I see. To avoid breaking those dependencies, I can just safely ignore the version conflict warning then, right?

Comment: @myrocks2 Consider voting and accepting the one answer that helped you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check for the dependencies from the dependency tree with the following command in **Linux**:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

or if you're using **Windows** try this:

```
gradlew.bat app:dependencies
```

Then, after you found the dependency with `support-v4:24.0.0` you can exclude it with:

```
compile('com.library.name:version') {
  //exclude group: 'com.android.support'
  //exclude module: 'support-v7'
  //exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
  exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: Thank You, You Saved Our Day... the last solution Works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `android` DSL:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
}
```

If `buildToolsVersion` is 25+, so should `compileSdkVersion`.

Since `buildToolsVersion` is 25+, then your support libraries should be as well:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In these situations when a library version is different from other versions, I suggest you **add that library in your dependencies with the version equal to others.**

In your case, you can add all libraries with version `25.3.1`.